# db.serverStatus() returns "not authorized to execute command" on mlab w/ owner privileges

Tags: mongodb

I recently opened up a free mLab account, and I'm trying to access the number of open connections in my database through the shell.

I never had problems with the command line when I was running mongodb locally, but now nothing works.

To connect I do this:

```
mongo ds127044.mlab.com:27044/db_name -u db_user -p db_password
```

And it show I'm successfully connected.

After that I run:

```
db.serverStatus()
```

And get:

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { serverStatus: 1.0 }",
    "code" : 13,
    "codeName" : "Unauthorized"
}
```

But according to my console I'm listed as the owner of the db:

```
{
"_id": "db_name.db_user",
"user": "db_user",
"db": "db_name",
"roles": [
    {
        "role": "dbOwner",
        "db": "db_name"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong in the command line or is it something particular to my account with mLab?

Answer (score 4):

Seems to be something related with your user's roles.

All documentation here: [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#cluster-admin-roles/](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#cluster-admin-roles) (specifically cluesterMonitor information)

Say:

> ...The admin database includes the following roles for administering the
>   whole system rather than just a single database...

And in this Doc https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-built-in-roles/

Say:

> Every database includes: **Database Administration Roles**... The
>   admin database includes the following roles for administering the
>   whole system: **Cluster Administration Roles**

'**serverStatus**' is realted to *clusterMonitor* role so..

Try to change it:

```
roles: [ { role: "clusterMonitor", db: "admin" },
         { role: "dbOwner", db: "db_name" }]
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Not a mongodb expert, but here's what I found in the docs.

[`db.serverStatus()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#output) shares instance info in its output.  For example:

> host
>
> > The system’s hostname. In Unix/Linux systems, this should be the same as the output of the hostname command.

mLab wouldn't expose host info to end users, who should only have access to the dbs they're creating--specifically, the db you logged into.

Similarly, you'll run into issues with other calls like `show dbs`, since that would expose all the dbs (including dbs for other users!) existing alongside your own.

I imagine that the only commands that will work are ones that expose info completely related to only your db.  I suggest hitting up a more export mongodb admin perhaps in a separate question for that definitive list, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this exact issue by changing my mac settings to allow remote login.

System Preferences -> Sharing -> Remote Login: On